# sorting a matrix relative to a function in matlab

Tags: function, matlab, sorting, matrix

how do I sort a matrix like for example

```
a = rand(4,4);
fx = sum(a,2);
```

now I would like to sort 'a' relative to the sorting of fx( so the rows of 'a' would change based on the values of the sorted fx)

```
fx = sort(fx);
```

Answer (score 3):

use the indices generated by sort function :  [MATLAB Help](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html#bup2pxc)

```
[~,I]=sort(fx);
fx=fx(I);
a=a(I,:);
```

Comment: thanks, it works but it returns just the first column of the 'a' matrix. How can I tweak it to return all the columns? thanks for your time